# NSTableVIew custom cell

Tags: objective-c

I trying to create custom cells for NSTableView for Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7

In 10.6 I am doing

```
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    CustomCell *tableCell = [[[CusomCell alloc] init]autorelease];
    return tableCell;
}
```

but how do I do this in 10.7?

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
}
```

The method in Mac OS X 10.7 returns `NSView` while CustomCell returns `NSCell`

I can't use NSTableCellView, as that will make the program not work on Mac OS X 10.6

I think that I can doing something like this, but I only have Mac OS X 10.6 and so I can't test this

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 299, 75)];
    [view addSubview:tableCell.controlView];
    return view;
}
```

Could someone check if what I am doing is correct? or maybe somebody know. how right doing in this situation

Comment: I am sorry, I can see that you may not be a native English speaker but I am finding it quite hard to understand what exactly you are asking for. I will try and answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use cell based NSTableViews in Mac OS X 10.7. They work the same as they did in 10.6, if you ignore the new features added in 10.7. Making your table view-based is entirely optional. So, if your table view works well in 10.6, it should work just fine in 10.7 as well. The `-tableView:viewForTableColumn:` is not at all right, and won't work. Just take it out, as it's unnecessary.

Comment: I can't use the NSTableViewCell. program is not run

Comment: you wont say me, if I comment this fuction viewForTableColumn, the method dataCellForTableColumn will be run in 10.7?

Comment: Yes, it will be called in 10.7. You should just ignore the changes made to NSTableView in 10.7. Since your app targets 10.6, it can't use them anyway, and they're 100% optional on 10.7. Think about it this way: if they were required on 10.7, any existing software that used NSTableView would have broken on 10.7, even though it worked on 10.6. That's obviously not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` in 10.7? It still works doesn't it?

Comment: I must comment - (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row this method ?